# jquery ajax call fails if there is a word alert() in the data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a jquery ajax call to validate the input text data.
When I enter value "alert()" inside the input text box, the ajax call is not made at all.
And the control directly goes to the success section.

```
    var myScript='alert()';
    $.ajax({
      url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ext/scriptTestServ',
      type:'POST',
      data: {
         script: myScript
          },
      success:
          function(response){
                  alert('no error');
          },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                 alert('error occured');
           },
         dataType:"text" 
     });
```

please help

Comment: What you mean when saying "fails"?

Comment: Try to check the response returning from server. in error callback, you can see textStatus. Try alert(textStatus); and also write alert(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: ajax call fails means that the call is  never made

Comment: Did you bind this do $(document).ready()? The url is ok? Check the console > network tab for errors (ctrl + shift + C in chrome ).

Comment: I get the following validation error  "Validation Error: One of the URL parameters include javascript."

Comment: I think you're sending javascript to the server...did you want to do that?

Comment: try `data: { 'script': myScript.toString() },`

Comment: What browser and version of jQuery are you using? How do you know the HTTP request isn't being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the text?

```
var myScript= escape('alert()');
```

Then on the server you'll have to URLDecode the input.

This way you're not actually send a script over.  You're still just sending over benign text.

Comment: Thanks although this has resolved the ajax issue, The page still crashes with the same exception ("Validation Error: One of the URL parameters include javascript") when I submit it to save the data.

Comment: I noticed that the issue specified in the comment above occurs only when I enter an opening  bracket or both opening and closing brackets after the word alert